# Spreedly Integration .Net Web App

Tags: c#, curl, command, spreedly

I'm thinking about integrating [Spreedly](http://www.spreedly.com) into my webapp to handle the payments & subscriptions. It's a .Net MVC app, however I could do the payment form in .Net Web Forms if needs be.

I'm just looking through the Spreedly API documentation, and the examples appear to use curl commands which I am very unfamiliar with, e.g. [example](https://spreedly.com/manual/integration-reference/programatically-creating-a-subscriber) .

I've googled (and maybe I'm googling for the wrong thing) and while I get lots of websites giving me lots of different examples of curl commands, I am still unsure how to actually use them in the context of a .Net web page?

Any help/links/etc to enlighten me would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a question that discusses implementing a cURL request using a C# WebRequest -

[cURL with user authentication in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152723/curl-with-user-authentication-in-c)

Here's the .NET binding on the cURL website -

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/dotnet/

Finally, this Google search got me a sizable number of results, which seem to be relevant to what you're looking for -

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=C%23+.NET+cURL

Comment: Thanks alot. Appreciate you taking the time to answer and point me in the right direction despite your patronising tone.

Comment: Sorry - didn't mean to come across as patronising! Just out of interest what was it about the answer that made you feel that way?

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented a [*NuGet* package](https://nuget.org/packages/Spreedly.Net) that could help you....

You can also browse the code on [***GitHub***](https://github.com/malixsys/Spreedly.Net) to see how `curl` maps to `HttpClient`, for example...