# Converting CURL request to C# for accessing Snipcart API returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest, snipcart

I am trying to access the Snipcart API (Reference - https://docs.snipcart.com/api-reference/authentication). I have created an API key and followed the steps mentioned in the documentation.

I am trying to Convert a CURL request to C#. I chose to use HttpWebRequest. I get 401 Unauthorized returned from the Server. I am not able to figure out what's wrong with my request.

Actual Curl Request: - curl -H "Accept: application/json" 
  https://app.snipcart.com/api/orders 
  -u {API_KEY}:

The following is the code that i tried converting the above curl request to

```
        string baseURL = "https://app.snipcart.com/api/orders";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseURL);
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        req.Accept = "application/json";
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.Headers.Add("API_Key", "MY_API_KEY_VALUE_COMES_HERE");

        string jsonResponse = null;
        using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
        {
            if (req.HaveResponse && resp != null)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write(jsonResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

The API reference from Snipcart says you need [Basic HTTP Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

When I have a look at your code, I think you should change this line

```
req.Headers.Add("API_Key", "MY_API_KEY_VALUE_COMES_HERE");
```

to

```
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("API_Key", "MY_API_KEY_VALUE_COMES_HERE");
```

A kind of the same issue is described in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152723/curl-with-user-authentication-in-c-sharp), you can take it as reference.

If it's not solving the issue, you could have a closer look at the [curl API parameters manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), and then translate it to C# code.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" \
  https://app.snipcart.com/api/orders \
  -u {API_KEY}:
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the header as a basic auth header instead of "API_Key" Try something like this.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseURL);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.Accept = "application/json";
req.Method = "GET";
var basicAuthHeader = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("MY_API_KEY_VALUE_COMES_HERE"));
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuthHeader);
```